# knn Imputation for features with mlr3 pipelines; tune value for k with nested resampling

Tags: r, knn, imputation, data-preprocessing, mlr3

I have another question concerning mlr3 pipelines. In my dataset some values are missing, so what I have learned from reading the literature it is best to delete the cases with missing values on the outcome and impute missing values in the features (not many in my case). Is this a valid approach?

For imputation I first wanted to do median/mode imputation, however it seems that knn might be a better solution?

However I am unanble to find a **code example on how to create a knn imputation pipeoperator, especially one that internally tunes the value for k** (I guess a manual selection such as sqrt(number of features) is not the best?)

I would be more than happy if someone could help me here.
Ideally I want to create a preprocessing pipleline in which, after scaling and one-hot encoding, all missing feature values are imputed with knn, but the value for k is tuned within the pipeline with nested resampling. (in that k is tuned within the knn pipop, followed by an AutoML Learner tuning its hyperparameters (e.g. ranger), everything is combined in a graph learner, the latter being evaluated in a benchmark experiment with (outer) resampling).

so together it should look like this:
glrn = as_learner(scaling numeric values → one-hot encoding for categorical values → knn imputation for missing values, number of k internally tuned with CV → random forest automated learner tuning selected hyperparameters)

If you think that this approach is actually not suitable for my problem, I am happy for any other suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to technically achieve what you want do do.
I cannot make any claims of whether this makes sense, as this is dependent on your problem. Stack Overflow is also not the correct place for this, as it concerns **coding** problems and no conceptual questions.

1. You can use the `po("imputelearner")` to impute missing values by fitting a learner. The docs are [here](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_pipeops_imputelearner.html)
2. If you want to tune the learner that imputes the features, you need to wrap the `learner` that you provide as a construction argument to the `PipeOpImputeLearner` in a  `AutoTuner`. You can construct a `AutoTuner` by calling `mlr3tuning::auto_tuner` and the docs are [here](https://mlr3tuning.mlr-org.com/reference/auto_tuner.html?q=auto_tuner). Here, it is important that the output of the `mlr3tuning::auto_tuner` is really just another learner and can be treated the same.